# Line Animation thickness is not consistent (SASS)

Tags: css, visual-studio, sass

The code snippet I posted below was for the line animation of two link classes, (cta-arrow and cta-alt-arrow) the animation works fine in my testpage (see html snippet) but the problem is when I zoom it in different levels when I adjust it into 90-75%, the thickness of the line in each link start to vary some are thin and some are thick it occurs randomly for different links below. I am not sure what element or attribute is causing this behavior. Hope you can help to make all the line animation for links consistent. Thanks in advance :) (NOTE that Iam using SASS I just convert it to CSS)

```css
a.arrow {
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}

a.arrow:before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 1.5px;
  width: 0%;
  -webkit-transition: width 300ms ease;
  -moz-transition: width 300ms ease;
  -o-transition: width 300ms ease;
  transition: width 300ms ease;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -3px;
}

a.arrow:hover:before,
a.arrow:focus:before {
  width: 100%;
}

a.arrow.cta-arrow {
  color: #004dff;
}

a.arrow.cta-arrow:before {
  background: #004dff;
}

a.arrow.cta-alt-arrow {
  color: #000;
}

a.arrow.cta-alt-arrow:before {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <h6>Text Link with Arrow</h6>
    <a class="arrow cta-arrow" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h6>ALT Link with Arrow</h6>
    <a class="arrow cta-alt-arrow" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h6>Text Link with Arrow and ALT Link with Arrow inside Ordered List</h6>
    <ol>
      <li><a class="arrow cta-arrow" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a></li>
      <li><a class="arrow cta-alt-arrow" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a></li>
    </ol>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h6>Text Link with Arrow and ALT Link with Arrow inside Unordered List</h6>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="arrow cta-arrow" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a></li>
      <li><a class="arrow cta-alt-arrow" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h6>Text Link with Arrow and ALT Link with Arrow inside Description List</h6>
    <dl>
      <dt><a class="arrow cta-arrow" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google Title</a></dt>
      <dd><a class="arrow cta-arrow" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google Description</a></dd>
      <dt><a class="arrow cta-alt-arrow" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google Title</a></dt>
      <dd><a class="arrow cta-alt-arrow" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google Description</a></dd>
    </dl>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h6>Text Link with Arrow inside a Paragraph</h6>
    <p><a class="arrow cta-arrow" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
      nascetur ridiculus mus. .</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h6>ALT Link with Arrow inside a Paragraph</h6>
    <p><a class="arrow cta-alt-arrow" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
      montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h6>Text Link with Arrow tagged as strong</h6>
    <a class="arrow cta-arrow" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"><strong>Google</strong></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h6>ALT Link with Arrow tagged as strong</h6>
    <a class="arrow cta-alt-arrow" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"><strong>Google</strong></a>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you're using Sass, why do you post your code snippet as the converted CSS then? It's much less readable...

Comment: Hi Kriszta, Sorry but I am a newbie here I can't find a 'sass type' code snippet where I can put my sass code. That's why I converted it to CSS.